# Laravel 7: Disable login & autologin (remember_token)

Tags: laravel, authentication, remember-me

I want to be able to disable certain users in my laravel 7 app. I therefore created a column "active" in the "Users" table and when set to active = 0 the user isn't able to login anymore.

The issue I have is the "Remember Me" function, since already logged in users still have access to the app after I disabled their accounts, because they don't have to pass the login form.

Will deleting the "remember_token" in the "Users" table have any effect on this? I tried this with a user (deleted the users remember_token in table) but it had no immediate effect, since autologin still worked after that. But maybe I'm missing something here.

Additional Info: I'm using Laravel Passport for authentication.

Comment: take the authentication middleware and add your condition to the section that authenticate the the user.

Comment: @N69S thx, you're right, will do.

Comment: You can reduce the session lifetime from `config/session.php` line : `'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),` , which will impact your remember me session, here 120 is minute

Comment: In event of setting active to 0, unset remember_me and delete the token.

Comment: ah I see, so, deleting the 'remember_me' token (thx @Tpojka) will take effect after the time defined in SESSION_LIFETIME (thx @sta). So by default 2h after deleting the 'remember_token' autologin won't work anymore for the user. So deleting the token would suffice with a delay of 120min (by default).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with the middleware solution, as I didn't want to reduce the overall SESSION_LIFETIME.

I created an extra middleware called "VerifyUserState", because I didn't succeed in reading the users "active" value via Auth::user() or $this->auth inside of the authenticate/handle function in Authenticated.php middleware.

I followed this tutorial to achieve  this:
https://www.itechempires.com/2019/08/how-to-create-configure-and-use-custom-middleware-in-laravel-5-8/

Now it works as needed.